# Euler-Cauchy Eigenvalue Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

Hi I'm trying to compare my leading order estimate for eigenvalues $\lambda_n$ for the following problem.
$$
\frac{d^2y(x)}{dx^2} + \frac{\lambda^2}{x^2}y(x) = 0\;\text{ with } y(1) = 0\text{ and } y(e) = 0.\label{1}\tag{1}$$

From the WKB method I got the result $\lambda_n = n\pi$ with eigenfunction 
$$
y_n(x) = B\sqrt{x} \sin(n\pi \log(x)).
$$

Then I solved \eqref{1} analytically by letting $y=x^m$ and then, proceeding in the usual way, applying boundary conditions I get the result 
$$
y_n(x) = B\sqrt{x} \sin (\frac{\sqrt{1-4\lambda^2}}{2} \log(x)).
$$ 
Then, if I apply $y(e) = 0,$ for non-trivial solutions I obtain 
$$
\lambda_n = \sqrt{\frac{1}{4} - n^2\pi^2}.
$$

Have I made an error here? I am trying to compare the leading order, but the analytical solution appears to give imaginary eigenvalues. Hopefully someone can steer me to the correct solution or fix my error.

Best.

Comment: By $y^\prime$ you indeed mean the derivative wrt. $x$? I.e: $y^\prime = \partial_x y$?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Made it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analytical solution missed a sign change in computing the complex roots. It should be
$$
y=\sqrt{x}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{4λ^2-1}}2\ln(x)\right).
$$
In detail, the characteristic equation for $m$ is $$0=m(m-1)+λ^2=(m-\frac12)^2+λ^2-\frac14.$$ For $λ>\frac12$ the solutions are a complex conjugate pair $$m=\frac12\pm i\sqrt{λ^2-\frac14}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much for correcting my erroneous ways!

Comment: Why do you pick the case where $\lambda$ is a conjugate pair?

Comment: Because otherwise you get real roots with solution $$y(x)=\sqrt{x}\left(x^{\sqrt{1/4-λ^2}}-x^{-\sqrt{1/4-λ^2}}\right),$$ where $y(e)=0$ can never be satisfied.